# JDK x64 fails to unpack in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, java

New to ubuntu, I have just installed the OS in my VMPlayer. I am trying to install Oracle (Sun) Java 6 onto my Ubuntu 13.

As per the instruction given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Manual_method) I download **jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin** from the official site. Followed further instructions of chmod as give in the link. But the unpacking step fails with the following error :

```
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
Extracting...
./install.sfx.29727: 1: ./install.sfx.29727: ELF: not found
./install.sfx.29727: 2: ./install.sfx.29727: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
Failed to extract the files.  Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of
the Installation Instructions on the download page for more information.
```

And a failed encoding file is created in the pwd.

`@@@�@8@@@@@@����@�@@@������@�@ (invalid encoding)`

I am not able to understand the error messages or the issue at hand. Please advice. How can I install java onto my system

Comment: Easiest way to install Oracle Java is using a PPA. https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java It's all prepackaged for you there. Why were you installing manually? Also note that there's OpenJDK - a free alternative to Oracle's. I would recommend using Oracle's only if you really need to - use OpenJDK if possible (in official repository).

Comment: i didn't know any other methods of installation. Plus the fact that every search result for `install java ubuntu` lead me to openjdk installations procedures, I tried the manual install

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. "All solutions describe OpenJDK packages, so I try manual Oracle JDK installer"? That does not make sense. Also read the page you linked yourself - it's giving this PPA as the first option for Oracle's JDK and explains why.

Comment: Oh!!! my bad!! I guess didn't notice the superuser link.. :)

Comment: Does he really need Oracle java or may be he don't know what OpenJDK is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Java SE 6 is archived, so please use 7 instead.

Personally I prefer to use the tar.gz package to manually install Java SE.

**Manual**

For example the latest => `jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Just extract it to somewhere,for example `/opt/jdk1.7.0_25`, set proper mode for the directory, write a script to set up java

Example: java7.sh

```
#Set JDK for all users
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_25
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH JAVA_HOME CLASSPATH
```

when you need to use java, just `. java7.sh` or `source java7.sh`.

You can add it to your `~/.bash_profile` (Ubuntu doesn't have this by default), so do it in `~/.profile` instead. You can do it for all users (system wide), up to you.

If you have multiple java versions, use `update-alternatives` to install / config.

`update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java" 1`
`update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/bin/java" 2`

Use `update-alternatives --config java` to manage.

**Shell script (kind of automated)**

Last but not least: [oab-java](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6) can be used to build .deb packages from the tar.gz provided by Oracle.